# Your opinion on "Unikong", this year's Stack Exchange Easter Egg for April Fools' Day?

Tags: discussion

I guess by now most of you have noticed that it's April Fools' Day again and that Stack Exchange is entertaining us with a new Easter Egg, like every year.

This year it's **Unikong**, a retro arcade game similar to Donkey Kong but with an evil unicorn as enemy and Jon Skeet (most famous Stack Overflow user) as your character.

I think it's a nice and funny idea, but the game itself is a bit boring, especially as it only has 4 small repeating levels and there's no multiplayer or any other kind of community interaction, not even the high-scores are real. That's the main reason I personally liked last year's easter egg better, the "Stack Egg" Tamagochi-like game where the community of a site had to vote for the action to be done on the next turn.

But that was only my personal opinion, of course. How do you think about it? I'm interested to hear your thoughts. How about the easter eggs from the years before? I'm only a member since 2015, so I don't know the older ones.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite nice except for the fact that it only has like 4 actually different levels, then it just repeats itself and gets harder in some ways, having at least 10 levels would be nice.

It would also be nice if when you are very close to a troll and you shoot it for the troll to actually die and not for the bullet (or whatever it is) just to go through it and for it to kill me anyway, that was a bit sad.

I agree with what Mark Kirby said in his post too, it would be good if the high scores weren't just local and would at least be for the site, plus the fact there there were others in the high scores list who weren't real was really strange... I at first thought that they were other people on the site, but then released that they weren't, still not sure exactly what they are meant to be. Perhaps just names for the different levels of points you can get.

The most annoying thing was that at first it did not fit in my browser, I later found out though that I could just make my browser [full screen or zoom out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277762/280862) so that solved that problem.

Like Mark Kirby though I lost interest in it after playing a few levels due to the lack of different levels and the lack of competition, as he said, it would be nice at least to get some sort of badge for getting a certain amount of rep in the game.

Generally though gaming for more than 20 minutes depresses me, so it's probably good that I am not that interested in this one.

Answer (score 1):

I quite enjoyed `unikong` for about 15 minuets but it has floaty controls and poor collision detection, so I lost interest fast.

It was fun however, you can get badges and earn rep but shooting the trolls did make me laugh a bit.

You are right though, the high score seems to be just for me locally and that sucks, I would of played again if I could compete (perhaps for a badge or something) with other users I know, that would of made it great.

As is, I guess it was a fun free distraction for a bit, I have no real complaints but once it is gone from the page, I am sure I would just forget it.

TL;DR

My opinion is `meh..` collecting hats at Christmas was a lot more fun.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing in your post I could disagree with.